# Apple Push Notification with XMPP Openfire

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, chat, openfire

I have developed a ios chat application in Objective C, which communicates to Openfire as XMPP server. I would like to implement push notification in my app so that if the user closed/killed my application, still he could get the messages from other users (like whatsapp). By analyzing several tutorials from google, I have managed to implement push notification codes in my app and using some application like [smart push](https://github.com/shaojiankui/SmartPush), I could able to send the push notification. But still, this functionality should be implemented in the Openfire server. I have installed the below plugins in the Openfire server. But I have no idea how to access those plugins. Can someone guide me with this?

[Plugin 1](https://github.com/myriky/XMPP2APNS)
[Plugin 2](https://github.com/xinminlabs/openfire-apns-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem too. But with `callBackOnOffline` plugin I solved this problem.
You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51041016/5853262) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51167471/5853262) to solve this problem.
good luck.