# When the app was terminated or the back ground is implemented, the push notification doesn't launch

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I am building a Hybrid Android app using Phonegap, HTML5, JavaScript and IDE(eclipse).

This app is the example app for the push notification. The push notification made based on the Java server.

But when the app is launched, the push notification is normally operated and when the app is terminated or it is launched in the back ground, the push notification is not opened.

Even when it does how, and the app is not executing, can the push notification be gotten?

[index.html - In hybrid app project]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
  /**
   * tokenHandler
   *
   * @param result      
   */
  function tokenHandler(result){
    console.log('deviceToken:' + result);
  }
  
  /**
   * errorHandler
   *
   * @param err
   */
  function errorHandler(err){
    console.log('error:' + err);
  }
  
  /**
   * successHandler
   *
   * @param result
   */
  function successHandler(result){
    console.log('result:'+result);
  }
  
  /**
   * onNotificationAPN
   *
   * @param event
   */
  function onNotificationAPN (event){
    if (event.alert){
      navigator.notification.alert(event.alert);
    }
  
    if (event.sound){
      var snd = new Media(event.sound);
      snd.play();
    }
  
    if (event.badge){
      window.plugins.pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, errorHandler, event.badge);
    }
  }
  
  /**
   * onNotificationGCM
   *
   * @param e
   */
  function onNotificationGCM (e){
   switch (e.event) {
    case 'registered':
    { 
     console.log(e.regid);
     $('#token').val(e.regid);
     break;
    }
    case 'message':
    {
     if (e.foreground){
      var soundfile = e.soundname || e.payload.sound;
      var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/" + soundfile);
      my_media.play();
     }
     else {
      if (e.coldstart) {
       console.log("Case : coldstart");
      }
      else {
       console.log("background");
      }
     }
     console.log(e.payload.title);
     navigator.notification.alert(e.payload.title);
    }
    break;
    case 'error':
     console.log('error:' + e.msg);
     break;
    case 'default':
     console.log('The event which it cannot know');
     break;
   }
  }
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
   console.log(device.platform);
   if(device.platform.toUpperCase() == 'ANDROID'){
    window.plugins.pushNotification.register(successHandler,errorHandler, {
     "senderID" : "My sender ID", // 
     "ecb" : "onNotificationGCM" // 
    });
   }
   else 
   {
       window.plugins.pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {
    "badge":"true",
    "sound":"true",
    "alert":"true", 
    "ecb": "onNotificationAPN"
    });
        }
     });
     </script>
     
     <script type="text/javascript">
      function insert(){
       var formData = $("#memForm").serialize();
       alert(formData);
       $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        data:formData,
        url:"http://192.168.0.26:9102/insertMember.do",
        success:function(data){
         alert("Success");
         location.reload();
        },
        error:function(request,status,error){
               alert("code:"+request.status+"\n"+"message:"+request.responseText+"\n"+"error:"+error);
        }
       });
      }
      
      function pushTest(){
       $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"http://192.168.0.26:9102/pushTest.do",
        success:function(data){
         alert("push Test!");
        },
        error:function(request,status,error){
               alert("code:"+request.status+"\n"+"message:"+request.responseText+"\n"+"error:"+error);
        }
       });
      }
     </script>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
   <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>hairShare</h1>
   </div>
   <form id="memForm">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content" data-inset="false">
     <input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" value="">
     <input type="text" name="id">
     <input type="password" name="pw">
     <input type="text" name="email">
     <input type="button" onclick="insert()" value="Submit">
     <input type="button" onclick="pushTest()" value="Push">
    </div>
   </form>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

[GcmTestServer() - In Spring MVC Web Project]

```html
@Controller
public class GcmTestServer {
 @RequestMapping(value = "/pushTest.do", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
 @ResponseBody
 public void pushTest() throws Exception {
  try {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   Sender sender = new Sender("AIzaSyBiJUHJ47I_eAZehDC0lx-1k5FSpcQPqyM"); // 서버 API Key 입력
   String regId = "APA91bFDd3srzd8UaaTFvCv4xheJ-WSXsU5eoQY8-veT1TSLQvDyXTtjSfiaw94nZjlj8nIonL6-PNw4lzKX0rb-bju8jnSbsMeQ93LGuvBGUuguOfwhCJ4"; // 단말기 RegID 입력
    
   String sendTlt = "send Title";
         String sendMsg = "send Message";
   
         Message message = new Message.Builder()
         .addData("title", sendTlt)
         .addData("msg", sendMsg)
         .build();
   List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
   list.add(regId);
   MulticastResult multiResult;
  
   multiResult = sender.send(message, list, 5);
   if (multiResult != null) {
     List<Result> resultList = multiResult.getResults();
     for (Result result : resultList) {
      System.out.println(result.getMessageId());
     }
   }
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

<---- Updated Contents ---->

Flag could be added according to @Mr.Rebot's answer and the information for was searched.

```html
Intent intent = new Intent("What does insert in here?");
intent.addFlags(FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);  
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Above can code be added to my MainActivity ?

[MainActivity.java]

```js
/*
       Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
       or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
       distributed with this work for additional information
       regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
       to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
       "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
       with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

       Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
       software distributed under the License is distributed on an
       "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
       KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
       specific language governing permissions and limitations
       under the License.
 */

package com.su.project;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*For Android*) It may be because of some changes starting from Android 3.1 where Launch controls behavior which when a stopped application will stop receiving any notification as "Apps that are in the stopped state do not receive broadcast Intents." Check this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37357745/is-there-a-way-to-receive-a-gcm-message-even-if-the-app-is-close-closed-by-slid) and [GCM push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838415/gcm-push-notification-works-after-app-force-stop/20838611#20838611).

> Note that the system adds [FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES) to all broadcast intents. It does this to prevent broadcasts from background services from inadvertently or unnecessarily launching components of stoppped applications. A background service or application can override this behavior by adding the [FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES) flag to broadcast intents that should be allowed to activate stopped applications.
>
> Applications are in a stopped state when they are first installed but are not yet launched and when they are manually stopped by the user (in Manage Applications).

Hope this information helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I understood your answer, but there was the part done not know well. Because the content that it would like to ask was long and it revised again to the body, the confirmation is asked.