# GCM Push notification when app is killed Android Pre lollipop

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-5.0-lollipop, marshalling

GCM push notification is not working in android when app is killed in some devices like lenovo and MI. Even after given permission from device still no help. I used `wakefulBroadCast` and `GCMListenerService`. But when app is killed, it is not getting message on Message Receive. I am stuck at this point. If anyone does this before please help and give some suggestions. Thank you in advance.

I'm not getting push notification when app is Killed or forcefully closed.

Comment: try this  quick start https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services

Comment: No this is not working in lenovo and Mi device not getting notification after killing the app

Comment: @SpartakTeam Post your logcat??

Comment: I also had the same problem.I switched to fcm.It works fine

Comment: @SpartakTeam Try changing the play-services gcm version from build.gradle.

Comment: I think this can be solved by using FCM new notification service ,but had to make lot of changes . :(

Comment: Not working after using FCM ,still not getting notification after killing the app ,this is happening only in Lenovo and MI phones and htc.

Answer (score 1):

You can read in this [blog](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/112013-how-multitasking-works-on-android-and-ios#comment-402624620) that closing an app by swiping it won't directly causes services to stop. It will only kill any background processes that exist for the process. Since you also tried using FCM and it's still not working, I guess that it's because of the device. As stated in the answer in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37357745/receive-gcm-messages-even-when-app-is-closed-slide-swiped-away/37429495#37429495), receiving notification even if the app was killed depends on the device where it is running. As you said, it only happens in Lenovo, MI and HTC phones. The reason you are no longer receiving pushes when the app is force-quit, is because the `Service` of these devices has also been force-quit.