# How to receive firebase messages even if app is killed?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

You want to receive notifications even when app in killed state.

You will generally use this snippet to read data from fcm :

```
class MyFcmListenerService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        Log.d("TAG","onMessageReceived: called")
    }
}
```

You will see onMessageReceived: called is printed in logcat when app is in foreground/background in some devices which have stock android. But in case of devices which have MIUI, ColorOS, OneUI etc. You will not see onMessageReceived in background because process is killed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code snippet can be used to receive FCM messages when app is in background/killed state

```
class BackgroundFcmReceiver : WakefulBroadcastReceiver() {
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    val extras = intent.extras?.keySet()
    if (extras != null) {
        for (key in extras) {
            Log.d("TAG", "$key")
        }
    }

}
```

As of developer documentation WakefulBroadcastReceiver is for an old pattern of implementing a BroadcastReceiver that receives a device wakeup event and then passes the work off to a android.app.Service, while ensuring that the device does not go back to sleep during the transition.
This class takes care of creating and managing a partial wake lock for you;

**Note : you must request the android.Manifest.permission.WAKE_LOCK permission to use it.**