# Firebase messaging Notification not show notification after force kill on Android pie

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-9.0-pie

Firebase Messaging Notification is not shown after force kill on *Android Pie* on **Infinix smart 4 model Infinix X653C** until device is restarted. All old notifications are also received at once when app is open and receives new notifications.

Comment: What's you question?

Answer (score 0):

Force stop kills all processes and stop the services.FCM is a service so it is stopped. Since your app has stopped it wont start unless user manually open the App.[Detailed Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37429495/4468665)